# Showing ergodicity of $T(x,y)=(x+\alpha, x+y)$ on the $2-$torus using Fourier series

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, dynamical-systems, fourier-series, ergodic-theory

Define $T: \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$ by 
$$T(x,y)=(x+\alpha, x+y).$$ Suppose that $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$. By using Fourier series, show that $T$ is ergodic with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Below is the solution to this problem. But I don't understand why the Fourier series of $f\circ T^k$ has the coefficients $a_{(n,m)} e^{2\pi i(nk\alpha + mk(k-1)\alpha /2)}$. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can explain this to me.

[image]

Comment: What happens if we replace $x$ with $x+k\alpha$ and $y$ with $kx+y+\frac{1}{2}k(k-1)$ in the term $a_{(n,m)}e^{2\pi i(nx+my)}$?

Comment: Why do we not get $mkx$ instead of $mx$ here?

Comment: My guess is that it's a typo. It should instead read $$\begin{align*} & \sum_{(n,m)\in \mathbb{Z}^2} a_{(n,m)}e^{2\pi i(nk\alpha+mk(k-1)\alpha/2)}e^{2\pi i((n+mk)x+my)} \\ = &\sum_{(n,m)\in \mathbb{Z}^2} a_{(n-km,m)}e^{2\pi i((n-km)k+(m(k(k-1)/2))\alpha}e^{2\pi i(nk+my)} \end{align*}$$

Comment: @MichaelLee You mean $nx$ at the end right?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fix one typo, create another...